# What is the best way to learn Differential forms?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, differential-forms

I'm taking a Multivariable Calculus class and my teacher has just started Differential forms. It is not making a lot of sense, though. I have tried reading "Geometric Approach to Differential forms" by David Bachman and I have understood a bit, but I would like to get more feel of it.

I just want an introduction to the subject, not too much detail. I want to know if there are any online lectures I can see or a better book I can read from.

Comment: Differential forms seemed like utter nonsense to me until I learned a little bit of topology.  I think it would have been easier for me if someone told me that no, it's not supposed to really make sense, it's all in the physicist's nonrigorous style.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Right now your question is rather broad: you are basically asking people to explain what differential forms are. Could you maybe narrow your question down somewhat more?

Comment: I added a little more information.

Comment: I don't think this was an unreasonable question. Since no one else provided you a source, I will suggest you look at my course lectures on *Multivariable Mathematics* on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd). Differential forms start at Lecture 24 of the second semester. (At the very end you'll find a re-do of that lecture, as there was a technical glitch the first year.)

Comment: Thanks Ted Shifrin, I'll definitely go through the lectures.

Answer (score 3):

The advice given elsewhere for doing math *homework* would seem  (to me) too apply *here* as well. ..  Namely,  step 1) write down the problem.   Step 2) cry.

That being said,  differential forms probably aren't any more difficult than any other topics in mathematics  (with the possible exception of tensors; which as I recall are closely related)...

Spivak's *Comprehensive introduction to differential geometry* is one source I remember. ..

Or maybe try guilleman and pollack's *differential topology*, or even Marsden and tromba's *vector calculus* has a section on them, I think...

Comment: The OP was doing a multivariable calculus course and you suggest Spivak?

Comment: I agree with @JohnMa Spivak is too elementary for the OP.

Comment: If anything it's too advanced. ..

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was downvoted nor do I understand why the question was upvoted. You learn differential forms the same way you learn to play the guitar. You practice.

Comment: @JohnDouma Although it was a while ago, however in my defense I was asking for a recommendation for a book or some lectures which would provide a good introduction to differential forms. Not how to learn it. Moreover, I didn't know how to learn to play the guitar, so I guess I couldn't have thought of 'practicing' at the time of asking the question.

Comment: @Sahiba  Maybe by making sense, you meant that you wanted some motivation. Which is totally ok. I don't know, what Douma's problem is. Maybe he does not care about things to make sense? Making sense of things and practising is not the same thing. If you still need it, you can check John M. Lee's book. I was personally satisfied by his motivation for Differential Forms.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this one: [A visual introduction to Differential Forms - Fortney](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-319-96992-3).

It's a nice book to see the geometric idea behind forms but without lost the formal formulation.